# Issue with httpPost.setEntity Android

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I'm trying to send data from an android application to a server using the following method:

```
public JSONObject  getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        try{
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            for (int i=0; i<params.size(); i++) {
                Log.v("askj",params.get(i).toString());
            }
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            try {
                Log.v("askj","HTTP Entity : " + convertStreamToString(httpPost.getEntity().getContent()));
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.v("askj",json);
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
```

I know for sure that I'm getting the parameters right, the url is fine, but this bit of code `httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));` doesn't work. The url that is being accessed is without those params. The `httpClient.execute(httpPost);` is simply accesing the initial url without any params. How can I solve this ? I tried to use an URI instead of the setEntity  but I don't know how to append a variable numbers of parameters at once.

Edit: I tested my service with Postman and the website can handle POST requests, so the problem is with the JSONParser.

Comment: note deprecation in default android http stack and look at using apache httpclient instead... http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity.html

Comment: Could you give me an example ?

Comment: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/httpmime/examples/org/apache/http/examples/entity/mime/ClientMultipartFormPost.java

Comment: I understood now what that refers to. I can use a URI for this, but I don't know how to loop through the List<NameValues> params because I sometimes send 2 values, sometimes send more. So I don't know how to append more queries with more values in params.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying encoding format like this:

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "utf-8"));
```

Comment: I get an error `in HTTPEnclosingRequestBase cannot be applied to URLEncodedFormEntity, java.lang.String `

Comment: you can only set an entity as a parameter I think

Comment: @BogdanDaniel Sorry, the encoding was for UrlEncodedFormEntity method.. See my updated answer and try again!

Comment: how have you confirmed that its not sending any params? use any tool like http://hurl.it and check if server is responding correct!!

Comment: Because I tested it. If I modify the url with some params in it I get them back properly, If I use setEntity with the base url nothing gets added to it because I don't get them back

Comment: and the server supports both get and post requests?